# Huge Space between title and plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph, data-analysis

how can I get ride of the huge white space between my title and plot(in pandas). Thank you.[image]

Comment: how many subplots do you plan to have?

Comment: I have 11 subplots

Comment: Have you tried to decrease the 50 in `figsize`?

Comment: If I reduce that figure, it works. But, it squeezes my plot upwards, and I don't want that.

Comment: If you have only 11 subplots you should use a different layout, for example (3,4) or something that multiplied gives you a value slighlty greater than 11. In your case there is allocating space for 5*6 = 30 subplots and that's why there is so much empty space.